# Rails 4: Order Loops depending on HTML Selector

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

I wanted to do that for a while now, and I am just missing the right approach I guess.
What I exactly want to do. I have a loop through items and just want to order them differently depending on what the User selected in an HTML Selector.

**For example:**

*Controller*

```
@items = Item.all
```

*View*

```
- @items.order("created_at DESC").each do |item|
```

In that instance `"created_at DESC"` should get exchanged with other lines of code depending on an HTML Selector.

Hope my question is easy to understand. Thanks in advance for each answer!

Comment: Do you want to be able to resort table columns?

Comment: @Moataz Zaitoun - No just the order of the elements - so I guess the rows. I am not outputting the data in a table, instead I am using an unordered list.

Comment: Would you provide the view code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've not provided sufficient info about the HTML selector you want to use I'll explain a very basic way to do so...

I'll assume that in the **items** index view you'll have to links one will sort **Items** by the date created `desc` and the other `asc`

So in your **items/index.html.erb** add the 2 links where you want

```
<%= link_to 'Sort asc', order: 'created_at asc', method: :get %>
<%= link_to 'Sort desc', order: 'created_at desc', method: :get%>
```

Then in your **items_controller.rb**, Replace the index action with the following...

```
@items = Item.order(params[:order])
```

But you should take care that passing a parameter directly to your controller is risky and put you in the hazard of SQL injection, You should sanitize it first. any way this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?autoplay=true) will help you a lot.

Comment: Thanks in advance!